# Wait for 5 candles to be drawn before buying after the last sell

Tags: pine-script

Look at the first Sell order in the picture. I want to make it not buy on the next 5 candles after each sell order. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common way to do it is to set your condition, which you will use to entry/exit positions to some variable, and then store last entry in some `var` varible.

```
//@version=4
strategy("strategy", process_orders_on_close = true)

var lastentry = -4  // var stores its value between bars

condition = bar_index%2==0 ? true : false    // some condition to enter / exit. enter at even bars. 

if (condition and bar_index-lastentry>=5)   // if there is 5 bars after last entry
    strategy.entry("EN", strategy.long) 
    lastentry := bar_index   //store bar_index 

strategy.close("EN", when = bar_index%3==0)   //close at bars which %3 == 0
```